# link folders via ssh

Tags: ssh, hyperlink, directory

I would like to do the following simple thing:

When a folder is referenced in a web site (i.e. href='folder1/pic.jpg'), I want the server to actually look in another folder (i.e. 'folder2'), where the actual 'pic.jpg' will be.

I believe this can be done by connecting to the server via SSH and then setting something up there, but I don't know what.

Could anyone give me an example?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the web server you're using, there might be a much simpler solution. Could you tell us what web server you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try going into your document root (`cd`) and executing

```
ln -s folder1 folder2
```

I think this is the thing in `ssh` you're talking about. Alternatively, you can edit server config there, but that requires more input.

Comment: Well, to nitpick a bit, this is not a "thing in ssh" but a feature of the operating system of your server. SSH just gives you a remote connection to the server's command line. Just so you don't search for it in SSH documentation :-)

Comment: Well, yes, I should've quoted "thing in ssh", of course. But to keep the spirit `ls` is a command, feature of the operating system is the corresponding syscall and the symlink itself is a feature of the filesystem :P

Comment: cool! believe that's what I was looking for, I remember something about 'ln'. Thank you very much!